# Inheritance in Babel transpiled ES2015 not working due to no class hoisting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am developing a web app and have my Javascript broken into multiple files. I am using Babel to transpile the directory of ES2015 source files to a single ES5 file. Coming from an objected oriented background I love having "classes" whether they are just syntactic sugar or not.

I recently created a base class in a file and then tried extending it in a different class in a different file. What I quickly realized is that class definitions are not hoisted and when Babel combined the multiple files the order is such that the base class in not defined yet when I instantiate the inherited class (so it throws a runtime error).

Here is a general example that illustrates what I am talking about:

base.js:

```
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log("BASE");
    }
}
```

derived.js:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("DERIVED");
    }
}
```

main.js:

```
var instance = new Derived();
```

Babel-CLI:

```
babel src --out-file index.js
```

results in index.js looking like:

```
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log("BASE");
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("DERIVED");
    }
}
var instance = new Derived();
```

This works fine. However, if I were to change the filename of base.js to xbase.js then index.js ends up looking like this:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("DERIVED");
    }
}
var instance = new Derived();
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log("BASE");
    }
}
```

this fails because the Base class is not defined before it is used:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Base is not defined
```

So clearly when Babel concatenates the files it grabs the file names alphabetically and sticks them together that way. How do I make this work without making sure my file names are named according to the order I want them to appear in the final file? Does using modules solve this problem? Is it the ONLY way to solve this problem?

Comment: Read [ask]. Post the code

Comment: You should be exporting stuff and importing the module, but without your code, there's no way to tell.

Comment: I didn't include the code because it was a general question, but have edited it with an abstracted example to illustrate. Hope this is more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) your files. That way, babel won't have to rely on file load order during concat of the files.

Example:

base.js

```
class Base {
    constructor() {
        console.log("BASE");
    }
}

export default Base;
```

derived.js

```
import Base from './base.js';

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log("DERIVED");
    }
}

export default Derived;
```

main.js

```
import Derived from './derived.js'

var instance = new Derived();
```